# Pegar nome da tabela respectiva PHP em SELECT UNION

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, pessoal tudo bem?

Alguém sabe como fazer para pegar o nome da tabela respectiva do valor puxado?

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$query= "
SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views FROM secao_aves UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views FROM secao_peixes
) as dados
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 3
";
```

Daí eu pego os dados e rodo o loop:

```
//PEGA OS DADOS
if($stmt_mvw = $mysqli->prepare($query)){ /* INICIA DECLARAÇÃO PRINCIPAL */

    //ABRE DECLARAÇÃO
    $stmt_mvw->execute();

    //TRAZ O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA
    $stmt_mvw->bind_result($titulo, $categoria, $views);

    while($stmt_mvw->fetch()){
        echo '<a href="busca.php?table='.$NOME_DA_TABELA.'">'.$titulo.'('.$views.' visualizações)</a>';
    }
}
```

Digamos que meu banco de dados esteja assim:

Tabela "**secao_aves**":

```
id |      titulo      | categoria | views |
1  |      Pardal      |     AA    |  250  |
2  |    Beija-Flor    |     AB    |  100  |
3  |  João-de-Barro   |     AC    |  145  |
```

Tabela "**secao_peixes**":

```
id |      titulo      | categoria | views |
1  |      Bagre       |     PX    |  180  |
2  |     Dourado      |     PY    |  165  |
3  |     Pintado      |     PZ    |  75   |
```

Até aí, tranquilo. Por exemplo, seria impresso isto (os 3 registros com mais "views"):

```
<a href="busca.php?table=<?>">Pardal (250 visualizações)</a>
<a href="busca.php?table=<?>">Bagre (180 visualizações)</a>
<a href="busca.php?table=<?>">Dourado (165 visualizações)</a>
```

Mas na verdade, eu gostaria que imprime-se assim:

```
<a href="busca.php?table=secao_aves">Pardal (250 visualizações)</a>
<a href="busca.php?table=secao_peixes">Bagre (180 visualizações)</a>
<a href="busca.php?table=secao_peixes">Dourado (165 visualizações)</a>
```

No caso, não sei como puxar o nome da tabela relativa ao dado, para criar a variável **$NOME_DA_TABELA** :/

Como proceder? :v

Comment: Tente colocar nas consultas internas algo como `select título, categoria, views, 'nome da tabela' as tabela`, assim cada registro terá o nome da tabela como uma coluna.

Comment: Opa, obrigado, Anderson. Fui ver as respostas agora. Obrigado novamente por se dispôr, realmente era algo simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um campo 'fictício' adicional dentro do SQL identificando a tabela:

```
SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views, tabela
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views, 'secao_aves' as tabela FROM secao_aves UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT titulo, categoria, views, 'secao_peixes' as tabela FROM secao_peixes
) as dados
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Assim, através do campo `tabela` você obtém a origem da linha resultante:

```
titulo  categoria   views   tabela
Pardal  AA           250    secao_aves
Bagre   PX           180    secao_peixes
Dourado PY           165    secao_peixes
```

Veja o modelo em: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6d0fd/3

Comment: Muito obrigado, Rogério por se dispor a mostrar de uma maneira mais direta. Com certeza é mais uma técnica pro eterno aprendizado. Um abraço!

Comment: Obrigado, lembrando para que dê a resposta como aceita, ok?

Comment: Prontamente. Estava testando hehe mas deu tudo certo. Até ;)